# Android resource linking failed. It refuses to build

Tags: java, android, xml

```
<declare-styleable name="ForegroundView">
    <attr name="android:foreground"/>
    <attr name="android:foregroundInsidePadding"/>
    <attr name="android:foregroundGravity"/>
</declare-styleable>
<declare-styleable name="PinPadView">
    <attr format="boolean" name="place_digits_randomly"/>
    <attr format="boolean" name="auto_submit"/>
    <attr format="boolean" name="vibrate_on_incomplete_submit"/>
    <attr format="color" name="pin_indicator_filled_color"/>
    <attr format="color" name="pin_indicator_empty_color"/>
    <attr format="dimension" name="pin_indicator_size"/>
    <attr format="dimension" name="pin_indicator_stroke_width"/>
    <attr format="dimension" name="pin_indicator_spacing"/>
    <attr format="integer" name="pin_length"/>
    <attr format="string" name="prompt_text"/>
    <attr format="color" name="prompt_textcolor"/>
    <attr format="dimension" name="prompt_textsize"/>
    <attr format="dimension" name="prompt_text_padding"/>
    <attr format="dimension" name="prompt_text_paddingTop"/>
    <attr format="dimension" name="prompt_text_paddingBottom"/>
    <attr format="color" name="button_textcolor"/>
    <attr format="dimension" name="button_numeric_textsize"/>
    <attr format="dimension" name="button_alpha_textsize"/>
    <attr format="string" name="button_text_numeric"/>
    <attr format="string" name="button_text_alpha"/>
    <attr format="reference" name="button_drawable"/>
    <attr format="dimension" name="button_drawable_size"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

This is the build error that shows and the code snippet above is where the error links to

[image]
This is what the error says

> ```
> /home/sylar/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/a07e4dae01600506a3ec419e8d952eb7/jetified-pinpad-1.2/res/values/values.xml:7:5-185:
> AAPT: error: resource android:attr/foregroundInsidePadding is private.
> ```

I do not know exactly how to solve it

Comment: Have you tried removing the android: prefix from foregroundInsidePadding?

Comment: I do not have anything like that in my project, except one of the dependencies I am using uses it. I can't seem to find the solution and i have been at it for over 5 days

Comment: Is that XML code not your own???

Comment: No, it wasn't, it was one of the dependencies I was using, once I downgraded that particular dependency, the  error left